# Why did my badges just disappear? Is it a bug?

Tags: support, badges

Just 20 minutes ago:
[image: 4 16]

Now:
[image: 2 1]

This might have something to do with the "Yearling badge" showing up twice here:
[image]

Comment: 4/16 on SO; 2/1 on MSO  different badge set

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You opened https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ .

Badges are saved on a per-site basis. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/ to see your set of badges on there.

You also got "Yearling" twice, because you've been a member of the Stack Exchange network for over 2 years (1 for each year), but apparently visited meta for the first time, today.